# pandas group by and concatenate n rows

Tags: pandas, group-by, concatenation

I have:

```
pd.DataFrame({'col2':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],'col':['one','fish','two','fish','left','foot','right','foot']})
```

[image]

I want to group by `col2` and concat every 3rd `col` to get:

[image]

I am trying

`dd.groupby(dd.index // 3).agg(' '.join)`

to no avail.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter per groups, then integers division by `3` and aggregate `join`:

```
s = dd.groupby('col2').cumcount()
df = (dd.groupby([s // 3, 'col2'], sort=False)['col']
        .agg(' '.join)
        .reset_index(level=1)
        .reset_index(drop=True))
print (df)
   col2              col
0     1     one fish two
1     1             fish
2     2  left foot right
3     2             foot
```